# Jasper Report with Buttun Jtable parameter

Tags: java, swing

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfDkr.jpg]

My Table

**strong text**
How to Great view a Report Invoice from parameter Jbutton Table (After Clik Button Jtable can Preview Database Click) ? please help me !

1. Creating a cooperative Invoice with invoice details on Frame DETAIL
   TABLE CONTRIBUTION.
2. When the process is going well, sy obstacles pd part JTable Button
   To Display Description The contents of invoices that have been made
   previously (such as images SC Upload)
3. Main problem is, how can I show ISI INVOICE through parameter JTable
   Button in a Column "OPTION" and when in Click "View details" will
   show Jasper Invoice Report in accordance with the selected table ??

ths Before it !

Comment: `How to Great view a Report Invoice from parameter Jbutton Table (After Clik Button Jtable can Preview Database Click` So what is your problem 1) handling the click of the button? 2) creating a Jasper Report? 3) something else?

Comment: My problem is when I click the button in the table (JTable button), I do not have any reaction ... I want, when I click on "view details" will appear in the form of jasper invoice report, but here I actually found "has no pages" , is there any solution or tutorial for me?

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is when I click the button in the table (JTable button), I do not have any reaction

You need to implement a custom editor for that column.

Check out [Table Button Column](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/). It shows how to use a button as custom renderer/editor for text in a column. Then you just provide the Action you want to be invoked when the button is clicked.

The column must be editable for the Action to be invoked.